# String replace with indication if replaced in one line

Tags: c#, string, replace

I'm looking for an efficient, case inventive string replace. If using Regex I don't want to call `Regex.IsMatch` and then `Regex.Replace` because that's unnecessary two searches through input instead of one. I could do the following but again this requires an additional local variable. Is there a way to do it in one line without a local variable? Something like `Regex.TryReplace(ref string input, ...)` that would return a bool.

```
string input = "string with pattern";
string replaced = Regex.Replace(input , Regex.Escape("pattern"), "replace value", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (!ReferenceEquals(replaced, input))
{
   input = replaced;
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with with a try/catch using the Replace(String, String, String, RegexOptions, TimeSpan)`overload.

```
  try {

     Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(words, pattern, evaluator, 
                                     RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace,
                                     TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25)));      
  }
  catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException) {
     Console.WriteLine("Returned words:");
  }
```

}

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_System_TimeSpan_)

But you are still performing two operations: trying to replace, and checking if it's replaced, which you'll always be doing. I'm courious on why such a concern of doing two operations in one line.

Comment: How does it relate to my question?